# How do I put integrals into an equation on Worldbuilding StackExchange?

Tags: support

I was trying to figure out how to put an integral into an equation in an answer on Worldbuilding StackExchange but I'm not sure how to?  How do I put an indefinite or a definite integral into an equation on Worldbuilding StackExchange?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/607/how-do-i-add-mathematical-notation-using-latex-mathjax - at least, it's answered there.

Answer (score 3):

The \int tag is used to put integrals in Latex. For example,

\int_a^b ! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x

becomes

$\int_a^b \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$

when Latex formatting is applied.

For further (and more detailed) explanation, see the [Latex int site](http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Int_(LaTeX_symbol)).